# "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'" when compiling typescript with google api libraries

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I just added `"@google-cloud/logging-winston":"2.1.0",` in my pacakge.json and when I compile I get the following errors. I have seen this with other google libraries occasionally, and its root cause is most likely deeper in the stack in automatic generated types from protobuf definitions.

```
../node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/build/proto/logging.d.ts:1434:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

1434                 line?: (number|Long|null);
                                    ~~~~

../node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/build/proto/logging.d.ts:1453:38 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

1453                 public line: (number|Long);
                                          ~~~~

../node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/build/proto/logging.d.ts:1543:39 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

1543                 requestSize?: (number|Long|null);
                                           ~~~~

../node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/build/proto/logging.d.ts:1549:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

1549                 responseSize?: (number|Long|null);
                                            ~~~~

../node_modules/@google-cloud/logging/build/proto/logging.d.ts:1576:42 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Long'.

1576                 cacheFillBytes?: (number|Long|null);
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I worked around this issue until it is taken care of.

1. In your package.json dependencies section add `"long":"4.0.0",`
2. In your package.json devDependencies section: add `"@types/long":"4.0.0",`
3. Finally, in tsconfig.json (add to tsconfig.app.js if that doesn't work) (or in the tsc command line) add:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "types": [
       ...
       "long"
     ],
   ...
}
```

Comment: This worked. Is there an official fix or something?. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea, from what I read I have concluded that the Google Cloud node libraries team quickly jumps to the latest typescript compiler for their modules without thinking through the implications to users who use their modules with older versions of the Typescript compiler. Hopefully, as long as you keep upgrading your Typescript compiler as well the issue will go away. And hopefully they will become more sensitive to such issues.

Comment: now this solution is not working :(

Answer (score 5):

gae123 suggestion did not work for me on typescript version 4.9.4.
I added the following to tsconfig.json. Hope this helps.

```
"compilerOptions":{
      ...
      "skipLibCheck": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding the `long` packet and `@types/long`, as gae123 suggested, but now the type is not to add in `tsconfig.json` but in `tsconfig.app.json`.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "types": [...,"long"]
}
```

Thanks gae123!